# Can't get CSS to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I can't seem to get a css file to apply its styling to a form.  It is quite frustrating now because as far as I know it should work!

In my head I have

```
<link href="/stylesheets/formtastic.css?1290524609" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and in the body I have:

```
<form action="/agents" class="formtastic agent" id="new_agent" method="post">
```

The formtastic.css file should apply styling to the form.  It's contents are viewable here:
[formtastic.css](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/blob/master/lib/generators/templates/formtastic.css)

Any suggestions or fixes?

Comment: Are you certain the path is correct?

Comment: Absolutely.  I view the source and I can see the code when I click the url.

Comment: Can you use Firebug or something to verify your CSS is even loading?

Comment: I have just verified in Firebug and it appears fine.

Comment: It's as if the selectors in the css file are just not working.  Can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the following code was not inserted in the form:

```
<% f.inputs do %>
```

This creates the html  and now the css works.

i.e. the html missing was

Comment: so really a rails question - you should tag accordingly

Comment: well this generates the necessary html, so not sure. but will do so anyway.

Answer (score 0):

dont you need to turn that number into a querysting var?

```
<link href="/stylesheets/formtastic.css?math=1290524609" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I don't need to do that.  This is to prevent caching and is done automatically by the web application framework (Rails)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this with Rails? If so, you could simply put this in your header:

`<%= formtastic_stylesheet_link_tag %>`

Also, have you run both `bundle install` and `rails generate formtastic:install` (for Rails 3, use `./script/generate formtastic` for Rails 2)?

Comment: Yes I am using Rails and I put that was the code in my header.  I have also ran the generator.

Comment: And you are also using Formtastic's DSL? I guess that you have already restarted the server, as formtastic_stylesheet_link_tag shouldn't work without doing that.

Comment: Does formtastic have any prerequisites in order to load the css?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the path is correct? if you check source with firebug check the link tag and see if its contents are a 404 error. It may be an issue with your root-relative path.

This is only a guess as I can't see how your site is structured.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have to begin with a forward slash ? (/)

Cause it's mean it's at the root of your domain.

Tried `<link href="stylesheets/formtastic.css?1290524609" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`  ?

Comment: The path does begin with a slash.